# Typescript typings - Duplicate name Promise / Cannot find name Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, typescript-typings

I'm building a client/server JS app and have a big problem using Promises. They are either undefined or duplicated and it seems to depend on the @types package.

```
npm install --save @types/es6-promise`
```

this will give server errors like this:

```
cd ../server 
➜  server git:(master) ✗ tsc
../node_modules/@types/es6-promise/index.d.ts(11,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
../node_modules/@types/es6-promise/index.d.ts(42,19): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'
.../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(4936,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(5261,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(5511,13): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(5737,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
➜  server git:(master) ✗
```

If I remove that package, then I get client errors:

```
tsc
src/components/GeneralChatAdminInputArea.tsx(100,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
src/components/GeneralChatAdminInputArea.tsx(103,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
src/routes/users/index.ts(11,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
src/routes/users/index.ts(12,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
src/routes/users/index.ts(13,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
```

What is the way out of this?

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "target": "es6",
        "jsx": "react",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true
    },
    "filesGlob": [
        "**/*.ts",
        "**/*.tsx",
        "**/*.tsd"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "buildOnSave": false,
    "atom": {
        "rewriteTsconfig": false
    }
}
```

here's another version showing the problem come and go

## client compiles fine

```
➜  author git:(402-compile-errors) ✗ cd client 
➜  client git:(402-compile-errors) ✗ tsc
➜  client git:(402-compile-errors) ✗ cd ../server
```

## but server fails

```
➜  server git:(402-compile-errors) ✗ tsc
../node_modules/@types/es6-promise/index.d.ts(11,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
../node_modules/@types/es6-promise/index.d.ts(42,19): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(4936,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(5261,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(5511,13): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(5737,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
```

## remove library and now server will compile

```
➜  server git:(402-compile-errors) ✗ rm -rf ../node_modules/@types/es6-promise 
➜  server git:(402-compile-errors) ✗ tsc                                      
➜  server git:(402-compile-errors) ✗ cd ../client
```

## but now client fails

```
➜  client git:(402-compile-errors) ✗ tsc
src/components/GeneralChatAdminInputArea.tsx(100,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
src/components/GeneralChatAdminInputArea.tsx(103,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
src/routes/users/index.ts(11,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
src/routes/users/index.ts(12,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
src/routes/users/index.ts(13,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
➜  client git:(402-compile-errors) ✗
```

So it seems like a catch22

Comment: Did unional's answer work for you? Where did you have to add that lib option?

Answer (score 1):

Missing `lib` in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: even if I am targeting es6? where on earth did this come from?

Comment: also I have separate tsconfig for client and server, where should that incantation go?

Comment: I've tried this and get `error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'lib'.` This is with `tsc 1.5.3`

Comment: Update your tsc. It is now 2.2